# Git log between two tags is blank, but Git log between the two sha is fine

Tags: git

I'm getting bizarre behavior when I try to get the history between two tags.

```
git log "build/tag1.1".."build/tag1.7" --oneline
```

**No results?**

But this if I use the sha1 from the dereferenced tags, this is fine.

```
git log 0810ff9..6e9a071 --oneline
```

I've also tried using the full ref names like `refs/tags/build/tag1.1` or `build/tag1.1^{}` or `build/tag1.1^0`

Using git 2.10.2.windows.1

Comment: Are the tags named like `build/tag1.1` or `build.tag1.1`. You've got it both ways in the above, and they are not equivalent. What does `git rev-parse <tagname>` tell you?

Comment: No, that's a typo. The biggest chore on SO is sanitizing the examples.

Comment: It gives me a hash of the commit it points to.

Comment: I've also tried not using quotes.

Comment: So do `git rev-parse build/tag1.1` and `git rev-parse build/tag1.7` resolve to `0810ff9` and `6e9a071` respectively? Thinking maybe your tags aren't pointing where you think they are. Also, possibly, they're on different branches, so that there is, in fact, no path from `build/tag1.1` to `build/tag1.7`...

Comment: Interesting guesses. But no, they are in a straight line in the history, no merges, no branching. I do get the expected results if I use the commits by hash.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are the culprit. Removing the inner quotes seem to help. On windows, bash doesn't care, but cmd.exe and powershell don't like the inner quotes.

```
git log --oneline "build/tag1.1..build/tag1.7"
```